# Configure app and MySQL DB in docker-compose.yaml - Could not open JDBC Connection

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, yaml, containers

I configured an app and mysql db within a docker-compose.yaml file below. While both services start, the app cannot open a connection to the DB when an http request is sent. When the app and mysql DB are defined in separate containers, the request succeeds. I am sure it is something simple in the docker compose config.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: docker_test-device-telemetry-mysql
    command: --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"

    volumes:
    - ./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
    - "6603:3306"

  device-telemetry:
    image: 224713337986.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/device-telemetry:2.5.0
    container_name: docker_test-device-telemetry-app
    volumes:
      - ./application.yaml:/application.yaml
      - ./bootstrap.yaml:/bootstrap.yaml
    ports:
      - "7857:7847"
    depends_on:
      - database
```

"timestamp": "2018-10-18T20:46:17.654+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException",
  "message": "**Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory** (Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)",
}

Comment: I am trying to help you but I am getting ERROR: Get https://224713337986.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/device-telemetry/manifests/2.5.0: no basic auth credentials

Comment: Hi. Authorisation credentials are required but are sensitive.  The question really is how the yaml file looks and if something obvious is missing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the reference to the url containing DB details in the application.yaml

It should be

url: jdbc:mysql://**database**:3306/local_telemetry

where database is the name of the DB defined in docker-compose.yaml

and not

url: jdbc:mysql://**127.0.0.1**:3306/local_telemetry